# Html Select box options on Hover?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I've seen this very simple selectbox on youtube, where the select options are visible on hover (instead of clicking), as seen in following screenshot.

[image]

I'm trying to create similar effect in the following simple select box. Can someone please help how this can be done? Thanks.

```
<select name="size">
   <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: The following answers are great https://stackoverflow.com/a/58011800/5092105 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46918464/5092105

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, though I'd prefer a more plug-in approach (rather than hard-coding the html `ul`):

```
$('#selectUl li:not(":first")').addClass('unselected');
// Used to hide the 'unselected' elements in the ul.

$('#selectUl').hover(
    function(){
    // mouse-over
        $(this).find('li').click(
            function(){
                $('.unselected').removeClass('unselected');
                // removes the 'unselected' style

                $(this).siblings('li').addClass('unselected');
                // adds 'unselected' style to all other li elements

                var index = $(this).index();
                $('select option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
                // deselects the previously-chosen option in the select

                $('select[name=size]')
                    .find('option:eq(' + index + ')')
                    .attr('selected',true);
                // assumes a 1:1 relationship between the li and option elements
            });
    },
    function(){
    // mouseout (or mouseleave, if they're different, I can't remember).
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x5YW3/).

---

**Edited** to include an `alert` demonstrating the changes in the `select` element's value: [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x5YW3/2/).

---

**Edited** to include the css and html used in the demo:

#### html

```
<select name="size">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>

<ul id="selectUl">
    <li>small</li>
    <li>medium</li>
    <li>large</li>
</ul>
```

#### css:

```
select {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
ul {
    width: 8em;
    line-height: 2em;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top-width: 0;
    text-indent: 1em;
    background-color: #f90;
}
li:first-child {
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

li.unselected {
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
ul#selectUl:hover li.unselected {
    background-color: #fff;
}
ul#selectUl:hover li,
ul#selectUl:hover li.unselected {
    display: list-item;
}
ul#selectUl:hover li {
    background-color: #fc0;
}
ul#selectUl li:hover,
ul#selectUl li.unselected:hover {
    background-color: #f90;
}
```

This causes the menu to hide the `unselected` items until the `ul` is hovered over, then revealing all the options, and uses the [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to assign the `unselected` class name to the non-clicked elements; which allows the clicked element to be still visible on mouseout.

The above CSS reflects the most-recent edit, to make the currently-selected, and `:hover`-ed, `li` more visible.

[Latest JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x5YW3/3/).

---

**Edited** because, well, I got a little bored. And had nothing better to do, so I made a simple plug-in:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.selectUl = function(){
        var $origSelect = $(this);
        var newId = $(this).attr('name') + '-ul';
        var numOptions = $(this).children().length;

        $('<ul id="' + newId + '" class="plainSelect" />')
            .insertAfter($(this));

        for (var i = 0; i < numOptions; i++) {
            var text = $(this).find('option').eq(i).text();
           $('<li />').text(text).appendTo('#' + newId);
        }

        if ($(this).find('option:selected')) {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
            $('#' + newId)
                .find('li')
                .not(':eq(' + selected + ')')
                .addClass('unselected');
        }

        $('#' + newId + ' li')
            .hover(
                function(){
                    $(this).click(
                        function(){
                            var newSelect = $(this).index();
                            $(this)
                                .parent()
                                .find('.unselected')
                                .removeClass('unselected');
                            $(this)
                                .parent()
                                .find('li')
                                .not(this)
                                .addClass('unselected');
                            $($origSelect)
                                .find('option:selected')
                                .removeAttr('selected');
                            $($origSelect)
                                .find('option:eq(' + newSelect + ')')
                                .attr('selected',true);
                        });
                },
                function(){
            });
                    // assuming that you don't want the 'select' visible:
                    $(this).hide();

        return $(this);
    }
        })(jQuery);


$('#sizes').selectUl();
```

[JS Fiddle demo, including the 'plug-in'](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wDSbT/).

Notes:

- This isn't absolutely positioned, so if you have more than one `select` (which you can certainly do, and works okay) it *does* screw with the page-flow a little (or a lot), but this can be amended in the CSS (I'd imagine, though I've not yet tried).
- It could probably do with some options, possibly allowing `dl` elements to be used in place of the current `ul`, which would allow for giving an explanation of the available options.
- I suspect that it could be optimised a great deal more than it currently is, but I'm not, off-hand, sure how. Possibly some sleep and, late, browsing the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) might offer some insights (though if anyone sees anything obvious please leave a comment! Or take the [JS Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wDSbT/) and, for want of a better term, fork it (though I'd obviously appreciate links to any subsequent forks/updates).
- I'm not entirely sure what licensing options are available to me (since everything on SO is [Creative Commons cc-by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/), according to [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/01/trouble-in-the-house-of-google.html), and the [footer](http://stackoverflow.com#footer) of this site, *anyway*), but for what it's worth I'm quite happy for anyone to take the above and, well, do whatever you like with it (if it's of any use, have fun!).

---

**Edited** because I felt that there should be a visible 'guidance' element, and also to try and explain something of how it all works.

Given the html:

```
<select name="sizes" id="sizes" class="makePlain" title="Select a size:">
    <option value="xxs">XX-Small</option>
    <option value="xs">X-Small</option>
    <option value="s">Small</option>
    <option value="m">Medium</option>
    <option value="l">Large</option>
    <option value="xl">X-Large</option>
    <option value="xxl">XX-Large</option>
</select>
```

Use the jQuery to call the plugin:

```
$('#sizes').selectUl();
```

This takes the above select, and creates a `ul` with the following mark-up:

```
<ul id="sizes-ul" class="plainSelect">
    <li class="guidance">Select a size:</li>
    <li>XX-Small</li>
    <li class="unselected">X-Small</li>
    <li class="unselected">Small</li>
    <li class="unselected">Medium</li>
    <li class="unselected">Large</li>
    <li class="unselected">X-Large</li>
    <li class="unselected">XX-Large</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS used (in the demo):

```
ul.plainSelect {
    /* targets those 'ul' elements created by the plug-in */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul.plainSelect li {
    /* this styles the 'selected' li 'option' element */
    background-color: #f90;
    display: list-item;
}
ul.plainSelect li.guidance {
    /* this is the 'Select a Reason' guidance/explanation from the image in the question */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: #fff;
}

ul.plainSelect li.unselected {
    /* hides the 'unselected' options, and removes the background-color for contrast */
    background-color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

ul.plainSelect:hover li,
ul.plainSelect:hover li.unselected {
    /* ensures that the 'li' elements pop-up when the list is hovered over, */
    /* and act/display like 'li' elements */
    display: list-item;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wDSbT/2/).

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to open a `select` box in the plain way your are describing. It is no coincidence that the image you have provided looks nothing like a normal select box. This is because it is probably actually a `ul` list which is styled to look as it does, revealing itself on hover, which is actually possible.

I created an example [over on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/Hracp/2/) of how it could be done.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this. Would it be possible for you to give a simple example using ul list, as you suggested? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in doing it this way, I've got a simple, non-javascript way of doing it on [my current project](http://cumberlandmaine.com) actually (look at the "I Want To" menu at the top). Like @Marcus said, this is not with a select box, but is done with a unordered list (`<ul>`).

The html is straightforward:

```
<div id="iWantToMenuContainer">
<ul id="i-want-to" class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://cumberlandme.info/contact">contact the town office</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://cumberlandme.info/upcoming-events">find out what&#8217;s happening</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://cumberlandme.info/online-services">get permits and services applications</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

the important part is the css, essentially just the first 2 rules.  The div appears to expand because of the `overflow:visible` on `:hover`.

```
#iWantToMenuContainer {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#iWantToMenuContainer:hover {
    overflow:visible
    }
#iWantToMenuContainer ul {
    border:1px solid #b6c2b9;
    background:#fff;
    padding:1px 20px 3px 5px
    }
#iWantToMenuContainer a:link,#iWantToMenuContainer a:visited {
    display:block;
    background: #fff;    
}
#iWantToMenuContainer a:hover {
    background:#e6e6e6
    }
```

Comment: +1 CSS only (and good example) - only issue I might suggest is that when you navigate somewhere, it's not shown in the menu.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @Steve. The `a:hover` has a slightly different background color to show what you're mousing over...

Comment: I think he means that when you are on a page like contact, this dropdown does not reflect the situation.

Answer (score 0):

At work at the moment so can't check youtube but from the styling I am guessing that that "select" control is not an actual select control.  Most likely it is implemented like a navigational drop down menu but instead of navigating to a url on click it replaces the contents and value of an input label.  Then on form submit it can pick up the value of the label.

Answer (score 0):

Link to the updated jquery plugin [Forked $.selectUI plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/qWkrp/1/)

- Fixes iteration over multiple elements passed in