# How do I style a select-box with gradients?

Tags: webkit, css

I'd like to style a select-box with some gradients.
My problem is that somehow there is a shadow added.
You'll see what I mean by opening [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaZ3A/1/).
The gradient of both classes is the same ...
I do not know why a shadow is added to the select-box and I just can't find a solution.
Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `select` element is handled by the underlying platform/OS, rather than the browser; as such it's not possible to style them (using Chrome 8/Win XP). If you feel the need to use styled `select` elements then you'll need to use a regular html element (such as an `ol` or `ul`) in combination with JavaScript.

I put together a demo of the ideas involved [for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover/4600178#4600178), which shows how this might be achieved: [JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wDSbT/).

I'm not sure what you mean by the 'shadow', although typically `input` elements are styled with a `:focus` pseudo-element rule, to indicate that the element has focus. This can be amended with:

```
select:focus {
    outline: 0 none transparent; 
}
```

Although this does reduce the accessibility of the form for those navigating with keyboards/non-mouse input-devices. Ideally, it's better to define an `outline` that fits with your site's design.