# Trigger click on select box on hover

Tags: jquery, click, hover, mouseover, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to have a `select` box automatically pop open when the use hovers over it, as if they had clicked it. Is this possible?

I would think I could do this easily with jQuery...

```
$("#settings-select").mouseover(
    function(){
        $(this).trigger("click");
    }
);
```

But that does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally got this to work! You need [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/); as others have pointed out, you can't do this with a normal `select` because there are no events available to use. But this will pop open the menu when you mouseover the `select` and close it when you mouseout, which is the exact effect I wanted.

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown" data-placeholder="Choose&hellip;">
    <option value="one">Option 1</option>
    <option value="two">Option 2</option>
    <option value="three">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#dropdown").chosen().next(".chzn-container").hover(
    function(){
        $("#dropdown").trigger("liszt:open");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).trigger("click");
    }
);
```

`$("#dropdown").trigger("liszt:open");` is what opens the menu. There is no equivalent `liszt:close` event to trigger when you want to close it (as far as I know), but triggering a `click` on it instead has the same effect.

Comment: Thank you. And a more elegant solution would be to change `$("#dropdown").trigger("liszt:open");` to `$(this).prev('select').trigger("liszt:open");`

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while but there is a solution I don't see here, using `hover` to change the length of `select` :

```
$('select').hover(function() {

  $(this).attr('size', $('option').length);
}, function() {

  $(this).attr('size', 1);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avdavQ

And here's a pen where it's a bit more than the bare necessity and has some styling :

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojbVya?editors=001)

Comment: I tried to add a value using your solution but it doesn't work.

Comment: try to use your demo and insert `value=...` for your options

Comment: Yes It works fine...sorry for that, yesterday I tried to add some `value=` and onhover didn't work (didn't open the dropdown).

Answer (score 2):

[trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) only call the functions bound via one of the binding functions of jQuery.

There is no cross-browser way to open a select from javascript (it *might* be possible to call `this.click()` on some versions of IE but I can't test, and I'm sure there is no way on other browsers).

Comment: Are you thinking of triggerHandler()? trigger() also fires the native event.

Comment: I don't think it fires the native event. *"For both plain objects and DOM objects, if a triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object, jQuery will attempt to invoke the property as a method if no event handler calls event.preventDefault()"*. That's different.

Comment: Ah, right, your last sentence nails it: selects don't have a click method.

Comment: In fact there is one, at least on Chrome and IE. But it doesn't do the same than a click on the select (I tried it on Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Working Example

```js
    $(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        $(".chosen-container-single").hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass("chosen-with-drop");
            $(this).addClass("chosen-container-active");
            $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:open");
        },function(){
            $(this).removeClass("chosen-with-drop");
            $(this).removeClass("chosen-container-active");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">
    
<div>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select"  style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>

          </select>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only implement your own select-box, or [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin, but this is bad for usability. Also think about `trigger('focus')`.

Comment: I'm using Chosen, actually. Does that make it easier/possible?

Comment: That makes it possible, but easier. Since Chosen replace `selectbox` with `div` element, you may manipulate events. Chosen probably have its own `_show()` and `_hide()` function, therefore something like `$(".chzn-container").mouseover(unknown_chosen_function());` might work, or not :)

Comment: hm...the function appears to be called `Chosen.prototype.results_show`, but I can't figure out how to trigger it properly...

Comment: Getting closer...triggering `liszt:open` on the Chosen `select` on mouseover will pop it open, but for some reason that only works if the `select` isn't active. And I also have to figure out a way to close it on mouseout...

Comment: Turcia: see my own answer to see how I solved this. You had the right idea using Chosen's own events.

Comment: daGUY; it's nice to see you find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the method with Chosen - did not work for me.

But I thought I could make my own selector on jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class='select'>
  <p class='input'>Select option</p>
  <input type='hidden' name='some_name_to_form' />
  <div class='hidden'>
    <p value='id_1' >option long value</p>
    <p value='id_2' >option 2</p>
    <p value='id_3' >option 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.hidden p').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.select').find('.input').text($(this).text());
  $(this).closest('.select').find('input').val($(this).attr('value'));
  $(this).closest('.select').trigger("change");
});

$('.select').change(function(){
  // ... do stuff
});
```

https://codepen.io/qwer643/pen/LebKpo