# jQuery: How to open/close dropdown menu by clicking on an image?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I would like to have the dropdown menu open and close by clicking on the image. Below is the html I have.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select_button1"><img alt="" src="images/button.gif" /></a>
<select class="select1">
      <option name="test" value="" class="first">Select</option>
      <option name="test" value="" class="">Opt1</option>
      <option name="test" value="" class="">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

This is what I've tried but does not seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select_button1').click(function() {
   $('.select1').toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: i) A '.' is missing in your click function selector. ii) What do you mean by open and close?

Comment: Looks like this is not currently possible!

Comment: Check this solution via using Chosen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622191/trigger-click-on-select-box-on-hover/

Comment: @Turcia Yes I've checked the solution using Chosen. That sounds good too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Evidently this is not possible, as techfoobar mentioned. What you can do is keep your select element constantly expanded and hide/show it on click.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select_button1"><img alt="" src="images/button.gif" /></a>
<br/>
<select class="select1" size="5" style="display:none">        
    <option name="test" value="" class="first">Select</option>       
    <option name="test" value="" class="">Opt1</option>       
    <option name="test" value="" class="">Opt2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.select_button1').click(function() {
    $('.select1').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYm4H/4/

Comment: this won't work, except your editing with the expanded select

Comment: @bukfixart Yes, that's why I edited it. I was pretty sure that was going to work though, because I've used that kind of hack to ease navigation around non linear forms. Another reason why you should always test your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible with default select boxes.
You could try to use a plugin for selectboxes or a self created. They often can be opened/closed with events.

Maybe this would be a way

```
$('.select_button1').click(function() {
  var $select = $( '.select1' );
  var options = $select.children().size();
  var size = $select.attr( 'size' );
  $('.select1').attr('size', ( size != options ? options : 1 ) );
});
```