# Dropdownlist on clicking on an image icon we have added in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my existing dropdown list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlMailSignature", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MailSignature, "Mail Signature", new { @class = "select2" })
```

Is it possible to get this same dropdown list using an image I have added in my application? Below is the CSS of my image.

```
.MailSignature {
  background: url(../img/signature.png) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: oh this answer is for showing the list on hover. but that cant help me I guess. then is it not possible to create a dropdown for an image on click?

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with default dropdown lists. But you could try to use a plugin for selectboxes which can be opened/closed with events.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622191/trigger-click-on-select-box-on-hover/).