# Need to work with mouse-over instead of dropdown

Tags: javascript

we have multi store view site with countires : India, USA, France

on top of the site we can see those 3 countries, once we click on dropdown-button [here](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/)

[image]

what we need is instead of clicking on dropdown button, it should work with "mouse-over"

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Your Language:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
$('select').hover(function() {

  $(this).attr('size', $('option').length);
}, function() {

  $(this).attr('size', 1);
});
```

It is playing with the `length` property of the `select`. Answered already here [Trigger click on select box on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622191/trigger-click-on-select-box-on-hover)

Comment: i am new to JS , can you please what is `function()` in above code in question ?

Comment: a declaration of anonymous function - a function without a name. The first function in the `hover` block is executed on mouse enter, the second on mouseleave

Answer (score 2):

In plain javascript syntax,

```
document.getElementById("select-language").onmouseover=function(){
  document.getElementById('select-language').click();
};
```

Also this Jquery script will do the job..

```
$("#select-language").mouseover(function(){
    $( "#select-language" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```

You can use any kind of selector,(#, . or tag)

Comment: i am new to JS , can you please what is `function()` in above code in question ?

Comment: that could open it, you need to come up with code that closes it on mouseleave also

Comment: @spylh9999ggr , Refer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky , he can write mouseleave function if he really need it, but it will be closed if he selects one option.

Comment: @sarath true that, but it won't close if you just open it and decide not to choose anything - you'll have to click somewhere outside, anyway it's a matter of UX and what the OP needs it for

Answer (score 1):

I would think that if you put onmouseover in the option it should work.

```
<option onmouseover="window.location.href=this.value" value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
```

Comment: i am new to JS , can you please what is `function()` in above code in question ?

Comment: @spylh9999ggr See updated code, don't know for sure if this works

Comment: @spylh9999ggr You do realize that i meant that you should replace this line with the line in your provided code right?