# Select option hover in and out jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select dropdown and certain number of options in that.

I want to change color of options whenever i hover in and out of the option.

Like :- when i hover on a option the color should turn to red and when i hover out i should be transparent again.

it is not working proper.

JS

```
$("select").hover(function (e){
    var $target = $(e.target); 
    if($target.is('option')){
        $target.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="select1" size="8" >
 <option>Ajwa Finance Ltd. </option>
 <option>Ajwa Fun World & Resort Ltd. </option>
 <option>Akar Tools Ltd.</option>
 <option>Akasaka Electronics Ltd.</option>
 <option>Akash Agencies Ltd.</option>
 <option>Akash Agro Inds. Ltd.</option>
</select>
```

Please help me with this

Thanks

Comment: posting some code code as well would help others to pick it up quickly!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Select List Option background colour on hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484053/change-select-list-option-background-colour-on-hover)

Answer (score -1):

The below question's answer will guide you to achieve that .

all the best :)

[Html Select box options on Hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover)