# How do I change the hover background of a dropdown?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown using the code below and all I want to do is change the background color to red when hovering over a specific salutation. Can someone please help me?

```
<div id="prefix" class="inputRow">
    <span class="inputLabel">Prefix/Salutation</span> <select
        class="inputPrefix" id="prefixList" title="Prefix or Saluation"
        tabindex=3>
        <option selected>Select</option>
        <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Ms.</option>
        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
        <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    </select>
</div>

.inputPrefix {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Although you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

Using this approach I don't think so it is feasible. Whenever you apply style then it applies on complete control. So **select** is the control. For this approach you can create dropdown using css. Because in that case dropdown structure in html looks like this

```
<div>
<span/>
<span/>
<span/>
</div>
```

Like here value saved in different **span** or we can say in **different** control. For this approach, you can learn about **telerik controls**. Check for it on google I think telerik can help you out. We use it mostly in .net, mvc. It's study will definitely provide you a better approach for fulfilling your requirement. It helps you to understand the formation of dropdown using div and span.