# Show value in textbox before selected from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#userID').change(function(){
        $('#username').val($('#userID option:selected').data('username'));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="nip" id="userID">
    <option value='1' data-username='user_id'>1</option>
    <option value='2' data-username='user_id'>2</option>
    <option value='3' data-username='user_id'>3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="name" id="username">
```

This code works to get selected value from dropdown list into textbox if I selected data first.

My question is, how to show data in textbox before I selected data from dropdown list?

Thanks.

Comment: I am fetching data from mysql into selection list

Comment: Edited. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: What data do you want to show in textbox before selecting from drop down list?

Comment: Edited. I mean if from dropdown list show value "1" first, in textbox show "1" too. Before select from dropdown list

Comment: Do you want to show data in textbox when you hover the mouse pointer on an option of the select box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mouse or keyboard events fire for option elements. 
See the msdn documentation for the events available in options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(VS.85).aspx

In this link you can see another approach to your problem:

[Html Select box options on Hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599975/html-select-box-options-on-hover)