# Hovering over an select open all options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

right now in my site I have a select with few options, when I click on it that select is open and see all options is there any way to made it on hover instead click?

```
<div class="control">
<select id="limiter" class="limiter-options" data-role="limiter">
<option value="24" selected="selected"> 24 per page </option>
<option value="48"> 48 per page </option>
<option value="72"> 72 per page </option>
<option value="all"> All per page </option>
</select>
</div>
```

I try this script but is not display well:

```
jQuery('#limiter').hover(function() {

  jQuery(this).attr('size', jQuery('option').length);
}, function() {

  jQuery(this).attr('size', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#limiter").mouseover(function(){
  $(this)[0].size=$(this).find("option").length;
});
$("#limiter").click(function(){
   $(this)[0].size=0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control">
<select id="limiter" class="limiter-options" data-role="limiter">
<option >Please Select </option>
<option value="24" selected="selected"> 24 per page </option>
<option value="48"> 48 per page </option>
<option value="72"> 72 per page </option>
<option value="all"> All per page </option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: exact same result as my solution...

Answer (score 2):

That is your best solution!
You have to change the select size `on mouseover`, and then change it back `on mouseout`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.open-on-hover").on("mouseover", function() {
    var l = $(this).find("option").length ;
    
    $(this).attr("size", l) ;
  }) ;
  
  $("select.open-on-hover").on("mouseout", function() {
    $(this).attr("size", 1) ;
  }) ;
  
  $("select.open-on-hover").on("click", function() {
    $(this).attr("size", 1) ;
  }) ;
});
```

```css
.holer{
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holer">
  <select class="open-on-hover">
    <option>Opt 1.1</option>
    <option>Opt 1.2</option>
    <option>Opt 1.3</option>
    <option>Opt 1.4</option>
    <option>Opt 1.5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="holer">
  <select class="open-on-hover">
    <option>Opt 2.1</option>
    <option>Opt 2.2</option>
    <option>Opt 2.3</option>
    <option>Opt 2.4</option>
    <option>Opt 2.5</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="holer">
  <select class="open-on-hover">
    <option>Opt 3.1</option>
    <option>Opt 3.2</option>
    <option>Opt 3.3</option>
    <option>Opt 3.4</option>
    <option>Opt 3.5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just simulate a click:

```
$('#limiter').hover(function() {
          $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: you exactly copied my solution - great performance mate...

Comment: the jquery(this)...but my answer isn't about jquery(this)

Comment: but this doesn't work does it?

Comment: btw I had taken it from the OP's answer...didn't know he posted your jquery(this)...

Comment: @inxoy I guess this makes it mine now?

Comment: problem is that (this) refers to #limiter and we want to simulate a click for the options not the select

Comment: @inxoy I'm not sure abt that...I take it the OP wants the select to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

For me your solution worked because I changed #sorter to #limiter because you have no such id like sorter

```
 jQuery('#limiter').hover(function() {

  jQuery(this).attr('size', jQuery('option').length);
}, function() {

  jQuery(this).attr('size', 1);
});
```

Comment: sorry limiter was there but I put the code wrong, because I have two select forms in my page

Comment: in my browser it doesn't look satisfying design wise but it works! how is it going for you?

Comment: I see only the first part of the first option, just a part from first option

Comment: could you please share a screenshot?

Comment: I prefer dev8080 answer, sorry mate

Comment: but it doesn't seem to work? or am I too blind to see